# Change a Object of a ViewController from a other Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

in the past 2 weeks I tried to solve this problem in Swift which I had.

I am quite new to Swift and developing IOS APP's. I want to change a property of an Label from a other Class. I know from other languages like Java that you can get the instance of an Class and change the Label from outside. But I don't know how to do this in Swift because I don't know where and how the ViewController is created as an Object.

I have a lot of sourcecode. That's why I created a simple Game and ViewController Class to show you my problem.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Points1: UILabel!
    var game = Game()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

```
class Game {
   
    func IncrementPoints() {
        //Here I want to Increment the Points by getting the Label from the ViewController
    }
}
```

**In my code it's very important that I change the Label or have access to the label from outside.**
In this easy Example it would be possible to execute this function in the ViewController but that is not possible.

I would be very happy if anyone could help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach and there are better ways to do it. But if you want to access label in game you need to pass current viewcontroller as argument in a function

```
class Game {
    weak var parentVC: ViewController?
    var points = 0

    func setVC(vc:ViewController){
       self.parentVC = vc
    }
    
    func incrementPoints(by value: Int) {
        points += value
        parentVC?.points1 = "\(points)"
    }
}
```

And in viewController pass self as argument

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Points1: UILabel!
    var game = Game()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        game.setVC(vc:self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are totally right that this way is not a good solution. But it solves my problem in the first case.